# MD5 hashes differs between .NET and dart/flutter

Tags: .net, flutter, dart, hash, md5

I'm trying to send hashed token to server which is written in .NET, but I get different hashes when using MD5 in Dart.

Any help would be appreciated

DART CODE:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

static String calculateToken() {
String salt = "uKaTtbmsEdHWdGv";
String tokenString = "test_string";
var bytes = utf8.encode(tokenString+salt);
var md5Bytes = md5.convert(bytes);
var newBase64 = base64.encode(md5Bytes.bytes);
return newBase64;}
```

.NET CODE:

```
string CalculateToken()
    {
        string salt = "uKaTtbmsEdHWdGv";
         string tokenString = "test_string";
        using (var s = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tokenString + salt)))
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(s));
        }
    }
```

Comment: so first find which one is correct - i believe you can find many md5 services online to find right checksum

Comment: Thanks, will have a look.

Comment: seems your checksum should be `c101be5a8b1986f4cd2c3af242a38a98`

Comment: As a sidenote, normally hases are shown as hex strings, not as base64 strings. Even if base64 is shorter (24 vs 32 chars for MD5)

Comment: And the base64 should be `wQG+WosZhvTNLDryQqOKmA==`

Comment: When I run the dart code I get the MD5 hash I am expecting, but I find it hard to believe that the .NET algorithm is suddenly incorrect after all these years. I'd do a comparison of each at every step of the process to see where the discrepancy is actually coming from.

Comment: Thanks All! After further investigation, I found out that the problem was in my tokenString, where I  use DateTime ticks and there .Net and Dart actually differs. Depending on If you use DateTime.now or DateTime.Utcnow